# gRPC and Minimal API in AspNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, ssl, grpc

My AspNetCore 6 project has a gRPC service and a Minimal API.

this is Program.cs file.

```
    builder.Services.AddGrpc(options =>
    {
       options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
       options.IgnoreUnknownServices = false;
       options.MaxSendMessageSize = 6291456;
       options.MaxReceiveMessageSize = 6291456;
       options.CompressionProviders = new List<ICompressionProvider>
       {
          new BrotliCompressionProvider(CompressionLevel.Optimal)
       };
       options.ResponseCompressionAlgorithm = "br";
       options.ResponseCompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
       options.Interceptors.Add<ExceptionInterceptor>();
       options.EnableMessageValidation();
  });
  builder.Services.AddGrpcValidation();
  builder.Services.AddValidator<CountryCreateRequestValidator>();
  builder.Services.AddGrpcReflection();
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<CountryManagementService>();
  var app = builder.Build();

  // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  app.UseRouting();
  app.MapGet("/info", () => "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a 
  gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
  linkid=2086909");
  /*    
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
     context.Response.ContentType = "application/grpc";
     context.Response.Headers.Add("grpc-status", ((int)StatusCode.NotFound).ToString());
     await next();
 });*/
 app.MapGrpcReflectionService();
 app.MapGrpcService<CountryGrpcService>();
 app.Run();
```

While project is running gRPC service works but API doesn't answer to request. On console appears this error

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
  HTTP/2 over TLS was not negotiated on an HTTP/2-only endpoint.
```

Comment: Perhaps start with the grpc tutorial first? https://grpc.io/docs/languages/csharp/dotnet/